# Как изменить расстояние между "плавающими" колонками в Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter, bootstrap

Как уменьшить отступ между "плавающими" блоками в Twitter Bootstrap?
По умолчанию, в Bootstrap отступ `20px`, необходимо его уменьшить до `5px` или до `0px`?

Поиск данного вопроса в Google и Yandex, не дал результата.

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Все работает, Но...
Если в head, после bootsrap.css поставить bootstrap-responsive.css, то отступ снова появляется. Хотя если его поставить перед bootstrap.css, то отступ убирается...
 Отсюда вопрос: нужен ли фаил bootstrap-responsive.css? Если да, то для чего, и каким по счету он должен находится в head.
Спасибо.

Comment: вся функциональность `bootstrap-responsive.css` присутсвует в `bootstrap.css`

Comment: То есть, другими словами, наличие в head ссылки на  bootstrap-responsive.css не имеет смысла и достаточно только bootstrap.css? Для чего тогда вообще нужен этот фаил?

Comment: И, надеюсь последний вопрос: как сделать, чтобы меню, при минимальном разрешении (visible-phone), скрывалось и открывалось по клику, так-же, как это реализовано на сайте http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: >достаточно только bootstrap.css?

да

>Для чего тогда вообще нужен этот фаил?

чтобы можно было использовать только функциональность предоставленную им без остальных комнонентов

>как сделать, чтобы меню, при минимальном разрешении (visible-phone), скрывалось и открывалось по клику

а разве это не по умолчанию работает?

Comment: Не нужно ничего редактировать, есть готовые классы https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На странице [Customize and download](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) отредактируйте переменную `@gridGutterWidth` как вам угодно